# Powershell odd behaviour when outputting to csv

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-csv

I'm having a problem when outputting my foreach loop to a csv file.

My Groups are set like this:

```
$Groups = "Group1", "Group2", "Group3"
```

My code is:

```
$results = ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
        $memberof = get-adgroup $Group | select -expandproperty distinguishedname
        Write-Output $Group
        Get-ADObject -Filter 'memberof -eq $memberof -and (ObjectClass -eq "user" -or ObjectClass -eq "contact")' -properties * | select name, Objectclass, mail
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Output ""
    }

$results | Export-csv  Contacts.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem seems to be coming from the Write-Output lines but I have no clue why. When I run my code without writing to a csv file, I get the expected result, something like:

```
NameOfGroup1
name                        Objectclass mail
----                        ----------- ----
User1                       user        User1@mail.com
User2                       user        User2@mail.com
                                                            #Spaces caused by write-output ""

NameOfGroup2
User1                       user        User1@mail.com
Contact1                    contact     Contact1@externalmail.com
```

Then again when I run my code to write to csv file and have the `write-output $Group` commented out I get a similar result.

But if I run my full code from the top of this page including the `write-output $Group`, it comes out like this:

[image]

I've figured out what these results represent but I haven't got clue why they do print out like this.

Eseentially the numbers refer to the length of the group name, so the first 17 would be a 17 character group name, and then the number of lines below is equal to the number of contacts and users that are inside that group. The 2 zeros at the end of each group are the length of the `write-output ""` lines.

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: I have no idea how your script is working to be honest. in your `Get-ADObject` command, you are trying to use a variable in single quotes. This won't evaluate the quote and will instead just use `$memberof`

Comment: `Export-Csv` converts an object or array of objects with properties into a CSV file. You can see the same result in the console with `ConvertTo-Csv`. Properties are converted into columns and property values are placed under their associated columns. When you output a string, it has a property of `Length`. To fix this, you need to add `$Group` as a calculated property in your `Select-Object`. If you want to do blank lines in your CSV, then you should output another object with all of the property values as `''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will closely output what you are attempting.

```
$results = ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
        $memberof = get-adgroup $Group | select -expandproperty distinguishedname
        Get-ADUser -Filter "memberof -eq '$memberof' -and (ObjectClass -eq 'user' -or ObjectClass -eq 'contact')" -properties name,ObjectClass,Mail | Select-Object @{n='Group';e={$Group}},name, Objectclass, mail
    [pscustomobject]"" | Select-Object Group,Name,ObjectClass,Mail
    [pscustomobject]"" | Select-Object Group,Name,ObjectClass,Mail
    }

$results | Export-csv  Contacts.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Explanation:**

`Export-Csv` converts an object or array of objects with properties into a CSV file. You can see the same result in the console with `ConvertTo-Csv`. Properties are converted into columns and property values are placed under their associated columns. When you output a string as in `Write-Output $Group`, it has a property of `Length`. To fix this, you need to add `$Group` as a calculated property in your `Select-Object`. If you want to do blank lines in your CSV, then you should output another object with all of the property values as `''`.

When you mix objects in your PowerShell outputs, you can see unexpected results. Your `Get-ADObject` outputs a custom object. Your `Write-Output` lines output a string. Those two object types do not share properties. So you only see the properties for the first object in your array, which is a string. If you put all of the `Write-Output` statements at the end of your loop, you will see more properties in your CSV. See below for an example that just by reversing the order of processed objects, you get a different result.

```
$str = "string"
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{property1 = "value1"; property2 = "value2"}

$str,$obj | convertto-csv -notype
"Length"
"6"

$obj,$str | convertto-csv -notype
"property1","property2"
"value1","value2"
,
```

Notice the properties available to the custom object `$obj` and the string `$str`.

```
$obj | get-member -Type Properties


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name      MemberType   Definition
----      ----------   ----------
property1 NoteProperty string property1=value1
property2 NoteProperty string property2=value2

$str | get-member -Type Properties


   TypeName: System.String

Name   MemberType Definition
----   ---------- ----------
Length Property   int Length {get;}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the only thing I had to change was Get-ADUser back to Get-ADObject as ADUser doesn't report contacts, apart from that it's working now.